# Setting column names in gota

Tags: dataframe, go, gota

I have a dataset without column names defined. How can I assign these programmatically using gota? For comparison, [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) has `df.rename`.

Say my data looks like this:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I basically want this in my dataframe:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `ReadCSV` with load options. In go, this method is called [functional options](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis).

This is the example in gota:

```golang
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("sample2.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer f.Close()

    names := dataframe.Names("A", "B", "C")
    noHeader := dataframe.HasHeader(false)

    df := dataframe.ReadCSV(f, names, noHeader)
    r := df.Records()

    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Functions `Load*` and `Read*` in gota all have `LoadOption`:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-gota/gota/dataframe